# I have a 2012 dodge journey and the a/c has to always be on and I wrecked the a/c condenser and radiator what do I need to refill for the a/c to work

Tags: ac

I'm trying to fix my 2012 dodge journey I hit a boar and dented the radiator, the radiator fan, and a/c condenser all of the fluids drained out on the count of the crash and I'm trying to fix the a/c now, so my car won't overheat what do I need to fill to make it work?

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking.  The A/C doesn't stop the engine overheating.  Can you  describe what you have already fixed, what you have replaced and what still needs fixing?

Comment: ok so ive replaced all the physical parts but i need to refill the a/c condenser with Freon both high and low but no idea how

Answer (score 0):

Thinks to do -

If you haven't already, you need to replace the receiver/drier.

Connect up an a/c manifold gauge set

Use an a/c vacuum pump to evacuate the a/c system of all air and moisture.  Let it run for at least 20 minutes.

Turn off the vacuum pump and check that the systems maintains a complete vacuum for half an hour or so. If it doesn't, you have a leak.  Fix the leak and try again.

While maintaining a vacuum in the system, connect the new refrigerant bottle. Flush any air out of the pipes connected to the bottle.  Usually the bottles need to be held upside down to ensure liquid refrigerant is pulled into the system.  Weigh the correct amount of refrigerant in, as in the car specs.

Alternatively, and highly recommended, get it refilled professionally.

Comment: ill try that hopefully it wont be to expensive

Comment: If you haven't already got the equipment, it is expensive.  Much cheaper to get it done professionally.

Comment: A few months late i know, but if you've replaced all these AC parts including the receiver/drier, you should probably also add a bottle of PAG oil.